# Why does npm install not add search.cmd?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I'm at my wits end here and no matter what I try, npm install will fail when it can't find the windows command file search.cmd. Here's my output

```
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save"
    npm ERR! node v4.4.7
    npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
    npm ERR! path c:\projects\sm\node_modules\.bin\search.cmd
    npm ERR! code EPERM
    npm ERR! errno -4048
    npm ERR! syscall open
    npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\projects\sm\node_modules\.bin\search.cmd'
    npm ERR!     at Error (native)
    npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\projects\sm\node_modules\.bin\search.cmd']
    npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
    npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
    npm ERR!   path: 'c:\\projects\\sm\\node_modules\\.bin\\search.cmd' }
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     c:\projects\sm\node_modules\npm-debug.log
    /c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 34: 12604 Signal 112              (core dumped) "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

I'm running node -v 4.4.7. Also tried with 5.11.0 and 6.3.1 also failed. Yes, I have full control assigned for everyone and their dog over the node_modules folder.

Comment: This issue has been around forever (as far as I can tell). I've seen it many times, but only on Windows. Seems to be related to one, more, or all of the following: old npm versions (with defects), anti-virus software, slow hard disk, permissions, <other cause>. I'd try the latest npm [`3.10.6`](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.10.6) if you can and maybe an `npm cache clean` first for good measure. I've seen `npm install -f` recommended as well, which has helped me in the past.

Comment: Your error does mention `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator` so that could also be a factor

Comment: I updated to npm 3.10.6, ran the bash.exe as administrator, cache clean, forced installation with --no-optional, and still the search.cmd is not installed.

Comment: Have you tried using plain DOS command prompt? I've experienced the same problem using bash (well gitbash) in Windows

Comment: Yes. Same result. For kicks, I updated my npm to 3.10.6 and node to 6.3.1. Wiped out my node_modules folder with a good ol fashioned rm -fr *, changed to the root of my project and ran an npm install again. To my amazement, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code as admin then the problem is with the npm cache. So fix it by using

> npm cache clean

command.

you can read more about this issue [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826)